# How To Set Initial Form Field Value From View in Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I am trying to set the initial value of a form field from my view.  I've read the documentation and some other questions on here and I can't determine why my case is not working.

In one form (CreateOrderForm) I am entering a value for the 'reference' field.  In my next view, I use .get to retrieve that input and then try to default the 'reference' field in the CreateManifestForm to be the same.  I get no error, but no value comes in.

Below is what I am attempting:

FORMS.PY

```
class CreateOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ('reference', 'ultimate_consignee', 'ship_to', 'vessel', 'booking_no', 'POL',
        'DOL', 'COO', 'POE', 'ETA', 'pickup_no', 'terms', 'sales_contact', 'trucking_co', 'loading_loc', 'inspector', 'total_cases', 'total_fob', 'freight_forwarder', 'commodity', 'is_airshipment', 'credit')



class CreateManifestForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Manifests
        fields = ('reference', 'cases', 'description', 'count')
```

URLS.PY

```
url(r'^add_manifest/(?P<reference_id>\d+)/$', add_manifest, name='add_manifest')
```

VIEWS.PY

```
def add_order(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateOrderForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            reference_id = form.cleaned_data.get('reference')
            form.save()
            return redirect('add_manifest', kwargs={'reference_id': reference_id})
    else:
    form = CreateOrderForm()
    objectlist = Customers.objects.all()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'objectlist': objectlist,
    }

    return render(request, 'add_order.html', context)


def add_manifest(request, reference_id):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateManifestForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('add_manifest')

    reference_id = request.POST.get('reference')
    form = CreateManifestForm(initial={'cases': reference_id})

    manifests = Manifests.objects.all().filter(reference=reference_id)
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'manifests': manifests,
    }

    return render(request, 'add_manifest.html', context)
```

I would expect that the reference field in the add_manifest view would equal the value entered in 'reference' in the CreateOrderForm, but I just get nothing.

**TRACEBACK**

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/andrews/Desktop/WBU/web_unit/unit/views.py" in add_order
  61.             return redirect('add_manifest', kwargs={'reference_id': reference_id})

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in redirect
  56.     return redirect_class(resolve_url(to, *args, **kwargs))

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in resolve_url
  147.         return reverse(to, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  389.             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /add_order
Exception Value: Reverse for 'add_manifest' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'kwargs': {'reference_id': u'45643'}}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['add_manifest/(?P\d+)/$']

Comment: you will get `reference_id` from **`request.POST`**, but your **`if request.method == "POST":.....`** block won't let you do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never pass the reference_id to add_manifest, so there is no way to use it there.

You need to pass it in the URL - your commented code was right, you just need to follow through and add it to the urlpattern and the view:

```
path('add-manifest/<int:reference_id>/', views.add_manifest, name='add-manifest')
```

...

```
# in add-order
return redirect('add_manifest', reference_id=reference_id)
```

...

```
def add_manifest(request, reference_id):
    ...
```

Comment: I am trying the above, but now I am getting there error "CreateOrderForm" object has no attribute get - have you any suggestion for what I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure you did `form.cleaned_data.get` and not just `form.get`? Show the full traceback (as an edit to the question).

Comment: you were correct I did miss using the cleaned data. However, now I am receiving an error for NoReverseMatch. I have updated my Views.py in the question to reflect my current code and also posted the traceback. Also, I did the URL as such because I am using Django 1.10 @danielroseman

Comment: My mistake, `redirect` takes the kwargs directly. See the updated answer.